# Mistake not found in the body of a function

Tags: python, function

I am testing a function that it suposse to return a list o words by opening a file. But instead of calling the file I just try that python read it. When I test this function appears the following error: "Wrong value returned on a one-line file" What could be wrong in this code?. My first though is that the replace value is incorrect or my loop could be wrong too but I don't know where.

PS: this code is made by keeping in mind that new lines are removed. 
Thanks in advance. Any hint will be useful.

This is my code:

```
def read_words(words_file):
    words_list = []
    words_list = words_file.readlines()
    for line in words_file:
        words_list.append(line.replace("\n", ""))
    return words_list
```

Comment: the function itself seems okay (except you may need to omit the third line). i guess the error must be due to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input has multiple words per line, something like this will makes more sense:

```
def read_words(words_file):
    words_list = []
    for line in words_file:
        words_list = words_list + line.split()
    return words_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you are appending to the same the variable (`words_list`) that you are iterating through

```
def read_words(words_file):
    words_list = []
    lines = words_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        words_list.extend(line.split())

    return words_list
```

Comment: but this still the stripped list of lines, not words.

Comment: Are there multiple words per line?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for mentioning, I edited the code

Comment: now you don't need `replace` since `split` does the job.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are right. It is late so I should get some sleep

Comment: @JemarJones no `split` takes care of all blanks including newlines. Try it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My bad, then my original answer was right aha, just undeleted it.